# Using Azure Service Bus to communicate between 2 organizations

Tags: integration, azureservicebus, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, message-bus

We wish to decouple the systems between 2 separate organizations (as an example: one could be a set of in house applications and the other a set of 3rd party applications). Although we could do this using REST based APIs, we wish to achieve things like temporal decoupling, scalability, reliable and durable communication, workload decoupling (through fan-out), etc. And it is for these reasons, we wish to use a message bus.

Now one could use Amazon's SNS and SQS as the message bus infrastructure, where our org would have an SNS instance which would publish to the 3rd party SQS instance. Similarly, for messages the 3rd party wished to send to us, they would post to their SNS instance, which would then publish to our SQS instance. See: [Cross Account Integration with Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/cross-account-integration-with-amazon-sns/)

I was thinking of how one would achieve this sort of cross-organization integration using Azure Service Bus (ASB), as we are heavily invested in Azure. But, ASB doesnt have the ability to publish from one instance to another instance belonging to a different organization (or even to another instance in the same organization, not yet at least). Given this limitation, the plan is that we would give the 3rd party vendor separate sets of connections strings that would allow them to listen and process messages that we posted and also a separate set of connection strings that would let them post messages to a topic which we could then subscribe to and process.

**My question is**: Is this a good idea? Or would this be considered an anti-pattern? My biggest concern is the fact, that while the point of using a message bus was to achieve decoupling, the infrastructure piece of ASB is making us tightly coupled to the point that we need to communicate between the 2 organizations on not just the endpoints, but also, how the queue/topic was setup (session, or no session, duplicate detection etc) and the consumer is tightly coupled to how the sender sends messages (what was used as the session id, message id, etc).

Is this a valid concern? 
Have you done this? 
What other issues might I run into?

Comment: Have you seen Event Grid? I think its intent is close to what you need.

Comment: @Mikhail EventGrid between 2 organizations could be an overkill. Also, w/o support for DLQ, EventGrid for business transactions is far from optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One name for the pattern for connecting service buses between organizations is "Shovel" (that's what they are called in [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html))

> Sometimes it is necessary to reliably and continually move messages
>   from a source (e.g. a queue) in one broker to a destination in another
>   broker (e.g. an exchange). The Shovel plugin allows you to configure a
>   number of shovels, which do just that and start automatically when the
>   broker starts.

In the case of Azure, one way to achieve "shovels" is by using logic apps, as they provide the ability to connect to ASB entities in different namespaces.

See:

1. [What are Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview)
2. [Service Bus Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus)
3. Video: [Use Azure Enterprise Integration Services to run cloud apps at scale](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2017/T119/)

Comment: The only thing missing currently (april 2018) is that Logic apps dont seem to have a connector to AWS SQS. That would make it awesome! Vote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/19712623-please-add-cross-cloud-connectors-such-as-connecto

Answer (score 2):

Using Azure Service Bus connections string with different Shared Access Policy for senders and receivers (`Send` and `Listen`) is intended to be used by senders and receivers with limitted permissions. Just like you intend to use it.

> My biggest concern is the fact, that while the point of using a message bus was to achieve decoupling, the infrastructure piece of ASB is making us tightly coupled to the point that we need to communicate between the 2 organizations on not just the endpoints, but also, how the queue/topic was setup (session, or no session, duplicate detection etc) and the consumer is tightly coupled to how the sender sends messages (what was used as the session id, message id, etc).

The coupling always exists. You're coupled to the language you're using. Datastore technology used to persist your data. Cloud vendor you're using. This is not type of coupling I'd be worried, unless you're planning to change those on a monthly basis.

Not more specific to the communication patterns. Sessions would be a business requriement and not a coupling. If you required ordered message delivery, then what else would you do? On Amazon you'd be also "coupling" to FIFO queue to achieve order. Message ID is by no means coupling either. It's an attribute on a message. If receiver chooses to ignore it, they can. Yes, you're coupling to use `BrokeredMessage/Message` envelope and serialization, but how else would you send and receive messages? This, is more of a **contract** for partied to agree upon.